# Ruby SCGI/XMLRPC client

Tags: ruby

How is it possible to talk directly to the rtorrent via scgi interface? Ruby's XMLRPC client from stdlib can communicate only over HTTP protocol and rtorrent is only SCGI capable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a starter:

```
#!ruby

require "xmlrpc/client"

class XMLRPC::RTorrent < XMLRPC::Client
  def do_rpc(xml, async=false)
    headers = {
      'CONTENT_LENGTH' => xml.size,
      'SCGI' => 1
    }

    header = "#{headers.to_a.flatten.join("\x00")}"
    request = "#{header.size}:#{header},#{xml}"

    TCPSocket.open(@host, @port) do |s|
      s.write(request)
      s.read.split(/\n\s*?\n/, 2)[1]
    end
  end
end

server = XMLRPC::RTorrent.new("127.0.0.1", '', 5000)
p server.call("system.listMethods")
```

it ignores async, rtorrent rpc is on port 5000.

more details: http://python.ca/scgi/protocol.txt